# Problems saving authentication credentials with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm making a simple Node.js API with Express and Mongo, I'll make a front-end with React in the late future but right now I'm just adding models and I'm getting the problem (with the 'users' model) that passwords are not being stored.

This is my code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const crypto = require('crypto');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    username: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true, lowercase: true, index: true},
    hash: String,
    salt: String
});

UserSchema.methods.setPassword = (password) => {
    this.salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
    this.hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 10000, 512, 'sha').toString('hex');
};

UserSchema.methods.validPassword = (password) => {
    let hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 10000, 512, 'sha').toString('hex');
    return this.hash === hash;
}

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('User');
```

I have two instance methods defined in my schema, the ones I can only access with an instance of that schema, and I'm trying to do it here:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const UserSchema = require('./User');
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

router.post('/users', (req, res) => {
    let body = req.body;
    const User = new UserSchema();

    User.name = body.name;
    User.username = body.username;
    User.email = body.email;
    User.setPassword(body.password);

    User.save((err, user) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send('There were problems while creating the user.');
        res.status(200).send(user);
    })
});
```

I'm creating a new instance of the schema, and accessing the instance methods with that instance, the problem is that it seems that the fields '**hash**' and '**salt**' affected by the instance method, are not being affected at all.

I'm printing the hash and salt in the console, they're being generated but not saved, in fact, when I check Mongo everything gets stored but the hash and the salt aren't. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `setPassword` and `validPassword` methods are arrow functions.
Arrow functions binds `this` to the context of the surrounding scope. In your case it will be the global scope.

Change your methods to regular functions and it will work:

```
UserSchema.methods.setPassword = function(password) {
    this.salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
    this.hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 10000, 512, 'sha').toString('hex');
};

UserSchema.methods.validPassword = (password) {
    let hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 10000, 512, 'sha').toString('hex');
    return this.hash === hash;
}
```

Comment: Let me check it and I'll tell you in a bit!

Comment: Sorry man, I've been very busy lately. Yes! It worked perfectly. Thank you. @victorkohl.